# Error tool:context! - XML

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I use the Android Studio application to create applications, frankly I am a novice user. but there was a problem I did not understand. I searched a lot and asked a lot of people and did not find any answer. I hope to find a solution to the problem.

The problem:

[image]

As shown in the image, **tool context** has an error (in red) ... although the written files are correct! I do not know what the solution is. But the problem is great. I can not even press "run" or see the image of the application. I mean, the text must be correct so I can create any application.
I want a quick solution, thank you!

Note: For java

Comment: Ok it is red, but what the error says? Open the "Event log" on the bottom right and post the errors

Comment: "But the problem is great." What does your IDE about the problem say?

Comment: wait, I want to take a picture

Comment: pleft Look at the picture in the replies..

Answer (score 0):

**LinearLoyout or LinearLayout**

Spelling mistake.

You have used

```
<LinearLoyout
.
.
.>
</LinearLoyout>
```

but you should use this see spelling.

```
    <LinearLayout
    .
    .
    .>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Correct it :)

Comment: Where is the mistake ?!

Comment: Spelling mistake... You used Loyout instead of Layout in you xml. see my updated answer

Comment: There is no difference !

Comment: Now I've noticed, thank you, unfortunately, the problem has not been solved.